# Why do I get an error about mismatched types when using TryFuture instead of the equivalent Future?

Tags: rust, future

I have the following working piece of code using `Future`.

```rust
use futures::{future, Future};

fn fut_res() -> impl Future<Output = Result<(), failure::Error>> {
    future::ok::<(), failure::Error>(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
    if let Err(e) = fut_res().await {
        println!("{:?}", e);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

From what I read in the docs I should be able to alter the code to use `TryFuture` as follows:

```rust
use futures::{future, TryFuture};

fn try_fut() -> impl TryFuture<Ok = (), Error = failure::Error> {
    future::ok::<(), failure::Error>(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
    if let Err(e) = try_fut().await {
        println!("{:?}", e);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

The compiler complains that `try_fut` must return the associated type `Output`, but this type by definition *is* `Result<(), failure::Error>`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:12
  |
9 |     if let Err(e) = try_fut().await {
  |            ^^^^^^ expected associated type, found enum `std::result::Result`
  |
  = note: expected type `<impl futures_core::future::TryFuture as core::future::future::Future>::Output`
             found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`
  = note: consider constraining the associated type `<impl futures_core::future::TryFuture as core::future::future::Future>::Output` to `std::result::Result<_, _>` or calling a method that returns `<impl futures_core::future::TryFuture as core::future::future::Future>::Output`
  = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```

How do I explain this to the compiler?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4a5260847e760c77ff3c0e33cb6111f) does not work because `tokio` is still in alpha, but there is also an appropriate `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax doesn't work at the moment. The docs for [`TryFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures-core/0.3.1/futures_core/future/trait.TryFuture.html#tymethod.try_poll) show that you have to wrap the `Result` in a `Poll` for the time being (the emphasis is mine):

> ```
> fn try_poll(
>     self: PinMut<Self>, 
>     cx: &mut Context ) -> Poll<Result<Self::Ok, Self::Error>> [−]
> ```
>
> Poll this `TryFuture` as if it were a `Future`.
>
> **This method is a stopgap for a compiler limitation that prevents us
>   from directly inheriting from the `Future` trait; in the future it won't
>   be needed.**

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78daa6a5e60df17d8334199c43fe1e36)

When this compiler limitation resolves, this approach will no longer be necessary and you will be able to do what you did (or something along the same lines)

### References

- [futures issue 1776](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/issues/1776)
- [futures issue 1777](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/issues/1777)

Comment: This is rather unsatisfying but I will accept it. Amount of the boilerplate code when using `TryFuture` is insane compared to `Futue<...Result...>`.